# Android: Guide user to pull to refresh

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, android, interface, feedback

I am using [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) in an Android device. I would like a visual feedback so that the user can know there is a "pull to refresh" feature enabled. What would be the best method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like something like the following  (the key is small and with sort of a fading arrow)[image] that can be found on this persons site [on android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/685)

I think the key is something that indicates that one can pull down which is symbolized by a downward arrow and a dotted tail or sort of a fading pattern. The tab around it is a nice touch but i am not sure its needed.

Heres what apple does

[image: iphone]

Some apps also just put a different colored text bar at the top and they literally say "pull to refresh" Though I would combine it with an icon if a user doesn't know english or what that means.

[image]

**Although it may be common knowledge for many users** and apps like facebook or twitter dont give any insight that theres pull to refresh, from my own tests 50% of users (my median age was around 40 years old) dont realize pull to refresh exists.

- To mitigate not slowing down advanced users you could just show this icon maybe the first 10 or so times the user is on that page then never show it again.
- Or have a screen overlay the first time or two explaining what it is.

**Consider if you even need pull to refresh though** [Not everyone is a fan](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3023421/why-the-pull-to-refresh-gesture-must-die)

> When they first made pull it refresh it was to add that feature and declutter your screen. However that may be less relevant in 2015. Also if your app autorefreshed and doesnt accept a user to manually poll then it may be pointless. Furthermore with things autoupdating there may be less of a need to pull to refresh. Lastly the pull to is starting to have other features such as the search box on the home screen of iOS 7+.

[Though others are still a fan of pull to refresh](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2014/01/ptr/)